# What is Mycroft Holmes' full name? Is there a mention anywhere?

Tags: character, sherlock

In the BBC *Sherlock* series, Sherlock mentions that his full name is William Sherlock Scott Holmes. Has there ever been a mention of Mycroft's full name anywhere? (including other series, books and DVDs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the BBC Sherlock series, Sherlock mentions that his full name is
>   William Sherlock Scott Holmes.

Actually that's not what Sherlock's real name is. Well as far as we consider Sir Arthur Conan Doyle as the original creator of the character, it's not. There's no mention of William Sherlock Scott Holmes in his original works, it is just [Sherlock Holmes](http://www.sherlockian-sherlock.com/the-name-of-sherlock-holmes.php).

Similarly, Mycroft in Arthur Conan Doyle's writings has always been called by Mycroft Holmes and nothing other than that.

> Has there ever been a mention of Mycroft's full name anywhere?

I haven't been able to track any article where BBC explains how/why they came up with that name of Sherlock's. However, there's a thing called [Sherlockian game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlockian_game) and as per one of the [Holmesian Speculations](https://bakerstreet.fandom.com/wiki/Holmesian_Speculation), *William Scott Holmes* is father Holmes.

> Nick Rennison's Sherlock Holmes: The Unauthorized Biography names his
>   father as William Scott Holmes and his mother Violet Mycroft.

Maybe that's how Sherlock inherited that full name (or that's why BBC chose that name). There are others speculations too, which do not go with his name unfortunately.

There's no other information about Mycroft's other/full name in those speculation though.

So, till this date Mycroft is just Mycroft Holmes.

Comment: "Actually that's not what Sherlock's real name is." It is in the BBC series. He doesn't have a sister named Eurus in the Conan Doyle books either, but he does in the BBC series.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's why I said, "*as far as we consider Arthur Conan Doyle as the original creator of the character, it's not.*" And in BBC's adaptation or any other adaptations, Mycroft is still Mycroft Holmes, at least I don't know of any other name. Have you found anything ?